# Facebook PHP SDK - Logout issue

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I am using the FB PHP SDK along with Code Igniter 2 Framework.

I have a registration page where I can display a link for the user to click and approve the app and give it access to their basic data and email. This seems to work fine (although I have set it to be a popup, it doesn't popup, it just shows in the same page!).

My problem is that after being logged in with FB, the page shows a logout link, which when click, should log them out (and therefore show the login link again) BUT it doesn't work.

I have a parameter set to take it page to a certain page, and that does work. Just for some reason the FB "session" stick around and the user stays logged in with FB.

Any ideas?

my code in my controller:

```
// Facebook Connect
    $fb_config = array(
        'appId'  => 'xxx',
        'secret' => 'xxx'   
    );

    $this->load->library('facebook', $fb_config);

    $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) {
        try {
            $data['user_profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            $user = null;
        }
    }

    if ($user) {
        $params = array('next' => 'http://localhost/game/index.php/game/login');
        $data['logout_url'] = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
    } else {
        $params = array('scope' => 'email, publish_stream, publish_actions', 'display' => 'popup');
        $data['login_url'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
    }
```

Last little question - should I even be using the PHP SDK, or should I use the Javascript SDK? I cant find any info on which one is best for whatever job?! Confused.com

Comment: What if you try the example shipped with php sdk? Does it log out current user?

Comment: Just tried it. Shows the same behaviour. Allows me to register with the app, logs in, can view details on page. Clicking "logout" does nothing, except for actually logging me out of FB (but not on the test php page!!!)

Comment: file a bug on php sdk github then probably

Comment: can you show us your "logout" process? when landing from Facebook (after clicking the logout link) are you calling `$this->facebook->destrySession();`?

Comment: @ifaour: it should have been called automatically I suppose https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L759 or https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L1119 ps: most likely I wrong about first reference since he uses `getLogoutUrl()`, but any exception should destroy session automatically

Comment: @ifaour my process is in that code. in my view i am simply creating an anchor tag that calls $data['logout_url'].

Comment: @Mr Pablo: how do you check in server side code that user is logged in? `$data['user_profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me');` -- this line should throw an exception if your facebook.com session doesn't exist (due to log out)

Comment: Exactly, it doesn't throw any errors, even though I click it and it takes me to the login page, specified in the $params. I just added a $this->session->sess_destory() to the login page too, and going back to register page, it is still logged in to FB!!!

Comment: so `$this->facebook->api('/me');` returns you current user even though you've logged out from facebook.com?

Comment: correct. hit the logout link on my page, check page again, still logged in. check facebook.com, i am logged out. hit my logout link again, go back to my register page, still logged in. all the time i am printing the $this->facebook->api('/me'); array to the view, always showing my details.

Comment: That's very strange... I don't believe it is possible ;-)

Comment: @zerkms, you may need to call the method yourself. @MrPablo, try having unique controller method for FB logout (i.e. set the redirect url for the `getLogoutUrl()` to point to this controller method). and in that controller method call the `$this->facebook->destrySession();`. Make sure you are using the new [repo](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk)!

Answer (score 3):

> should I even be using the PHP SDK, or should I use the Javascript SDK?

If your app can be created with the JavaScript SDK instead of the PHP SDK, then go for it. Save your server's CPU cycles for something else. It also allows you to perform login asynchronously which can be nice.

Complex apps usually use both the JavaScript SDK and the PHP SDK -- in which case login is often handled on the Javascript side (the PHP SDK automatically knows if the user logged in via JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that after being logged in with FB, the page shows a
>   logout link, which when click, should log them out (and therefore show
>   the login link again) BUT it doesn't work.

This cause by your website cannot clear fb session. I have same problem when use facebook api in cakephp framework. And ... I try to clear session when user logout (I don't like it).
I debug and see that when facebook account login successful,`$this->facebook->user()` not null and throw no exception.

Comment: Yea, sounds like the same issue. I just managed to clear the FB session, but it messed up the login!

Comment: @Mr Pablo: not the same issue at all. As you remember - you **can** perform additional api requests, which is just impossible

Comment: @MrPablo I don't know about Code Igniter authentication. In cakephp, I allow user login with user_id and facebook_id (have just been requested from facebook API) <br/>

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an active user access token added to the logout link for the logout link to work.

refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLogoutUrl/

**example:**

```
if ($user) {
  $params = array (
  access_token => ''.$access_token.'',
  );
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
} else {
$params = array(
  scope => 'read_stream,publish_stream,publish_actions,read_friendlists',
  //redirect_uri => $url
  );
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
};
```